# Find and sort directories

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need to find directories not older than 30 days and then sort them by date (newest to oldest).
This is my command:

```
find /tmp/logs/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime -30
```

The problem is obviously the sorting part :)

Comment: can't you call sort with the results? `find /tmp/logs/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime -30 | sort` ?

Comment: that sorts the dirs, not by time

Comment: That only sorts them alphabetically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are only "few" directories, you could pipe `find`'s output to `xarg ls -t`, e.g.:

```
find /tmp/logs/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime -30 | xargs ls -td1
```

Answer (score 3):

Do your find from above, then use this at the end:

`find -printf "%A@ %f\n" | sort -rn`

That tells find to print the time (in seconds) and the filename. You can sort on the time and there you go. Pipe *that* into `cut -d" " -f2-` to strip the time back off if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime -30)
do
    echo -n $f " "
    stat -c %Y $f
done
```

gives you the logs with modification dates. Sorting on the seconds should be easy.