# Sorting Files (including files in all subdirectories) by modification time

Tags: linux, file, list

On a Linux terminal, is there a way for me to list all the files that are either in the parent directory or any number of subdirectory levels below, all sorted by modification time across the entire files list?

`ls -Rlt` doesn't quite suffice, since it sorts by modification time for files per each subdirectory..

Comment: You could use `find`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5581361/516433

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you want

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS %p\n'|sort
```

Sample output:

```
20130312134959.5090000000 ./servlets/servlet/target/reporting_app.servlets.servlet/WEB-INF/lib/java-foundation-1.1.20.jar
20130312134959.7580000000 ./servlets/servlet/target/reporting_app.servlets.servlet/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-rolling-appender-1.2.15.jar
20130312134959.8050000000 ./servlets/servlet/target/reporting_app.servlets.servlet/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
20130312134959.9140000000 ./servlets/servlet/target/reporting_app.servlets.servlet/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
...
```

Comment: Brilliant ... - I obviously missed `find`'s option `printf`.

Comment: Thank you, man :) From your command I make best variant for me: find /etc/ -type f -printf '%TH:%TM %Td-%Tm-%Ty  %p\n' | sort > Desktop/list.txt

Answer (score 1):

What about using `find` like this:

```
find /my/dir/to/scan -type f -exec ls -lt --time-style=+"%F-%T" {} ";" | sort -k 6
```

This might take some time until it returns due to the final `| sort`.

In case you change the format by adding/removing options to `ls` you propably need to adjust the sort column, which currently is `6`, the date.